# Plot a polynomial of two variables without giving the variables' limits

Tags: polynomials

How to do make Plot automatically figure out a domain interval?
what I mean to say is "I have a cubic polynomial with two variables "lambda" and "k".where as lambda is a function of "k". i.e lamda(k)
I want to plot the equation free from the limits.
the equation is here:

$$\lambda^3 + c_1 \lambda^2 + c_2 \lambda + c_3 = 0$$
[image: full polynomial by adding C1,C2,C3]

plot lambda vs "k"
I am adding the code also here but it gives me some error

Comment: Please add the code that gives the error, and also code for lambda.

Comment: What limits?  How do you know beforehand that the polynomial is bounded?

Comment: Kiro 
thanks dear for your reply 
I am getting this notification while adding the code
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: David G. Stork
Thank you so much Sir,
actually in matlab you just put the polynomial and use the built in function "ezplot(@(k,x)function(k,x))" will give you the plot between the required variables. Matlab automatically choose the range for the variables
I am just looking for the same in Mathematica>

Comment: No, `ezplot` in MATLAB plots over $-2\pi..2\pi$ by default. It does not determine the range in a smart way.  If you want an automatic plot range, use `WolframAlpha`. I find the question unclear without an explanation of what criteria you expect the automatically chosen plot range to satisfy, and at least one concrete example.  Otherwise, even if there is an answer, I expect your next comment to be: "this is not the plot range I wanted".

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the question is that a basic plot of f(x,y) is needed. There is no information of what D or j are and there is no mention of plotting the solution of a system of equations (as a region I mean).

```
 Plot3D[x^2 + 2 x*y + x^2, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

This produces a typical 3D plot over axes  `x, y, z=f(x,y)` . The brackets do not bound the polynomial but just give the region over which it is plotted (they can be "sufficiently large" but `{x,:inf:,:inf:}` will not work.

[image]